# Mysqli_fetch_array wont show result. I dont know whats wrong

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to print out results from mysql using the mysqli_fetch_array function but It returns nothing. Everything is correct.
I dont get any errors.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Internet11!");
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn , 'hr');
$ResultSet=mysqli_query($conn, "select ssn, fname,lname,salary from employee");
?>

<html>
<body>
<TABLE>
 <TR>
     <TD>SSN</TD> <TD>FIRST</TD> <TD>Last</TD> <TD>Salary </TD>
 </TR>

   <?   while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($ResultSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {?>
 <TR>
     <TD><? echo $rs["ssn"] ?></TD>
     <TD><? echo $rs["fname"] ?></TD>
     <TD><? echo $rs["lname"] ?></TD>
     <TD><? echo $rs["salary"] ?></TD>
 </TR>
<? } ?>
</TABLE>
</body
</html>
```

Comment: Missing `;` after every `echo`

Comment: Missing `php` after each `<?` tag opening. Example: `<?php echo $rs["ssn"] ?>`, `<?php } ?>`

Comment: i fixed it. Still not working

Comment: @bpanatta it didnt work

Comment: Then you should be getting an error of some sort, probably from MySQL. Can you share it?

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump( mysqli_error( $conn ) );` to get the error.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte There is no need for trailing semicolon if you have `?>` They are the same

Comment: you can write `<?=$rs["ssn"] ?>` `<?=` means `<?php echo `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php   while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($ResultSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {?>
 <TR>
     <TD><?php echo $rs["ssn"] ?></TD>
     <TD><?php echo $rs["fname"] ?></TD>
     <TD><?php echo $rs["lname"] ?></TD>
     <TD><?php echo $rs["salary"] ?></TD>
 </TR>
<?php } ?>
```

try this format of code you need to write proper syntax of php block that is `<?php ..... ?>` every time when you want to assess php function or variable

Comment: *try this* is not an answer. explain what you have changed an why

Comment: i explained what i understand with this code

Comment: you don't really need to write like that `<?=` as valid as `<?php echo`